# Use serializer validated data in get_queryset()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to write custom get_queryset() method for serializer based on query params.

Here is my serializer:

```
class SearchRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    nickname = serializers.RegexField(
        r'^(?!(.*?\_){2})(?!(.*?\.){2})[A-Za-z0-9\._]{3,24}$',
        max_length=24,
        min_length=3,
        required=False,
    )
    modelA_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=11, min_length=11,
                                      required=False)

    def validate_modelA_id(self, value):
        queryset = modelA.objects.filter(id=value)
        if queryset.exists():
            return queryset.first()
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_('Not found'))
```

If object of modelA exists - validation will return an instance. But I 
don't want to perform the same query in get_queryset() in my if branch.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
    nickname = self.request.query_params.get('nickname', None)
    queryset = User.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=name)|Q(nickname__contains=nickname))
    if 'modelA_id' in self.request.query_params:
       # in this case will be annotated extra field to queryset
       # extra field will be based on 'modelA' instance which should be returned by serializer
    return queryset
```

I found only one solution - add the following line in my GET method:

`self.serializer = self.get_serializer()`

Than it will be possible to get validated values in my get_queryset() method. But PyCharm don't like this solution

Comment: I think re-writing the validation logic in `get_queryset()` method will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm under strong impression that you are misusing the Serializer. After quick analysis of your issue i think you need [DRF filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering)

Serializers process [`request.data`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data) which under the hood is just Django `request.POST` and `request.FILES` yet in your `get_queryset` implementation you make lookups in [`request.query_params`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) which in Django terms is `request.GET`. Check the DRF docs on this.

In order to achieve what you need with Serializers you would have to abuse the Views, Serializer Fields and Serializer itself. It is simply not what its supposed to do.
Additionaly I don't think that you need so much validation on search.

Customization and use of [Django Filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) should solve your problem.

```
class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'nickname', 'modelA_id']

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        name = self.form.cleaned_data.get('name', None)
        nickname = self.form.cleaned_data.get('nickname', None)
        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(name__contains=name)|Q(nickname__contains=nickname))
        if 'modelA_id' in self.form.cleaned_data:
            # in this case will be annotated extra field to queryset
            # extra field will be based on 'modelA' instance which should be returned by serializer
        return queryset


class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = UserFilter
```

> **NOTE** I did not test code above but it should show you how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Did I understand you correct, that I shouldn't validate `request.GET`?

Comment: If you are just searching for user, there is no point of validation. Validation is a mean to give feedback to user when for example submitting data. Here you are only searching. Did you ever seen anywhere that search gives you an error "You cannot search that. Its forbidden" Usually you search by whatever user wants and if it happens that you don't find anything you just return empty results. If search doesn't alter your data you don't need to validate anything.

Comment: In my example I'm searching user and also I need to add information about user's relation with specific object, in this case it's ModelA. So if model_id doesn't exist in my DB then I will annotate this relation status as None?

Thank you for explanation, I saw a lot of people who validate request.GET and I thought that it's right

Comment: @Ernst I don't exactly know what you want to annotate and what you will do with it but you can put your logic in `filter_queryset` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

How is about `user = get_object_or_404(queryset, id=ModelA_id)`. It looks better as for me.
`get_object_or_404` will catch an object you need, or will raise `Not Found` responce.

Comment: Your answer is only about validation of `model_id` field. The main question was about   `get_queryset()` method